# How to get back Ubuntu login screen

Tags: linux, boot, xfce, ubuntu-11.10

Before Ubuntu would show a list of window managers to use in the beginning. Now it just goes into one xfce. I remember changing something to make it automatically login and skip that screen but now I forgot what I did. In order to get to that screen, I have to log out.

How can I get that selection screen to show up at startup again?

Answer (score 1):

Change here

```
System> Administration> Login Screen
```